# no me sale consulta inner join,

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Tengo un pequeño problema, tengo el examen el día 15 y no me aclaro con los *inner join*; aquí tengo 3 tablas, y en el primer ejercicio tengo que mostrar el nombre del cliente y la cantidad total todas sus ordenes, ordenado por nombre de cliente. Yo lo he intentado pero no se que hago mal, gracias.

Yo he intentado con esto:

```
SELECT 
    customer.CUST_NAME AS "NAME", 
    orders.ORD_AMOUNT AS "Order Amount",    
FROM customer 
INNER JOIN customer ON customer.CUST_CODE = orders.CUST_CODE 
INNER JOIN orders ON customer.AGENT_CODE = orders.AGENT_CODE
GROUP BY customer_CUST_NAME;
```

[image: dd]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema o error? ¿Qué estás obteniendo y qué esperas obtener?

Comment: En los JOIN la tabla que indicas en el FROM no se repite de nuevo, a no ser que las quieras incluir dos veces. Si ya pusiste `customer`  en el FROM, en los JOIN debes ir agregando las otras tablas, por ejemplo: `FROM customer 
INNER JOIN orders ON customer.CUST_CODE = orders.CUST_CODE 
INNER JOIN agents ON orders.AGENT_CODE = agents.AGENT_CODE` De todos modos se ve una especie de relación circular en tu imagen: tienes `AGENT_CODE` tanto en `orders` como en `customers`  ¿? Debes explicar claramente cómo se relacionan tus tablas si quieres que te ayudemos mejor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tus errores son:

- Estás incluyendo dos veces la tabla `customer` sin ser necesario. Incluyela una única vez
- Estás utilizando el campo `AGENT_CODE` para los joins, cuando no es necesario. No lo utilices a menos que la consulta incluyera la tabla `agents` o las especificaciones del reporte solicitado indicaran que debe tomarse en cuenta al agente, cosa que no indica.
- La relación entre `customers` y `orders` es por el campo `cust_code`, así que ese es el que debiera figurar en el `join` entre ambas tablas.
- Para obtener el total de las ordenes del cliente, utiliza la función `sum()` sobre el campo `ord_amount`.
- Te hace falta una cláusula `order by` para cumplir con el requisito de que el resultado esté ordenado por el nombre del cliente.

No quiero entregarte el SQL de la consulta resuelto, ya que considero que es importante que lo logres por ti mismo. Dejame comentarios si tienes dudas y vemos como, al final, logras resolver el ejercicio.